# Defining type of function depending on special conditions

Tags: c++

I want to ask, which is ***the right and neat way*** to declare a function, which's returntype depends on a condition.

That's how I solved this problem at such a bad situation (without creating a function):

```
const QAudioFormat::SampleType signalSampleType;
typedef decltype(signalSampleType == QAudioFormat::Float ? float() : (signalSampleType == QAudioFormat::SignedInt ? int() : unsigned int())) sampleType;
std::vector<sampleType> rawSignalData;
```

Would that be fine, or is there a better way to do such things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a use case for [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional)

```
using sampleType = typename std::conditional<
                     signalSampleType == QAudioFormat::Float,
                     float,
                     typename std::conditional<
                       signalSampleType == QAudioFormat::SignedInt,
                       int, unsigned int>::type
                   >::type;
```

Which can be made a bit less ugly with c++14:

```
using sampleType = std::conditional_t<
                     signalSampleType == QAudioFormat::Float,
                     float,
                     std::conditional_t<
                       signalSampleType == QAudioFormat::SignedInt,
                       int, unsigned int>
                   >
```

Comment: Wow, very fast answer :) ! Thanks alot :)!